# Trouble creating unique instances of a class

Tags: c#, class, sorting, instance

I've been working on a class that implements different sorting methods. 
`myTest.bubblesort(sortMe, false)` returns a sorted list in ascending order. I've checked this behavior it works fine. `backTest.bubblesort(sortMe, true)` returns the same list sorted in descending order. I've check this behavior it is correct.

Where I'm running into trouble is that the `backTest` instance of `TestSorting` is acting like it's a reference to the `myTest` instance. When the `backTest` object is changed, it also modifies the `myTest` object. In other words, they are not unique instances as I expected. Can someone explain why?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] sortMe = Sorting.GenerateTestArray(10, 100);
        TestSorting<int> myTest = new TestSorting<int>();
        TestSorting<int> backTest = new TestSorting<int>();
        int[] test = myTest.BubbleSort(sortMe, false);
        int[] testBack = backTest.BubbleSort(sortMe, true);
    }
}

class TestSorting<T> where T : IComparable
    {
       public T[] BubbleSort(T[] sortMe, bool descending)
        {
            if (!descending)
                return BubbleAscending(sortMe);

            else
                return BubbleDescending(sortMe);
        }

        private T[] BubbleAscending(T[] sortMe) 
        {
            bool stopMe = true;
            int stopRecurse = sortMe.Length - 1;
            int optimizeMe = stopRecurse;

            for (int i = 0; i < stopRecurse && stopMe; i++)
            {
                stopMe = false;

                for (int j = 0; j < optimizeMe; j++)
                {
                    if (sortMe[j].CompareTo(sortMe[j + 1]) > 0)
                    {
                        Swap(sortMe, j, j + 1);
                        stopMe = true;
                    }
                }

                optimizeMe--;
            }

            return sortMe;
        }

        private T[] BubbleDescending(T[] sortMe)
        {
            bool stopMe = true;
            int stopRecurse = sortMe.Length - 1;
            int optimizeMe = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < stopRecurse && stopMe; i++)
            {
                stopMe = false;

                for (int j = stopRecurse; j > optimizeMe; j--)
                {
                    if (sortMe[j].CompareTo(sortMe[j - 1]) > 0)
                    {
                        Swap(sortMe, j, j - 1);
                        stopMe = true;
                    }
                }

                optimizeMe++;
            }

            return sortMe;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why should it act differently if it is acting on the same exact `sortMe` data?  Put the data in that class and they will act independently even if the data elements are the same

Comment: I don't follow.  Your class has no state (member variables or properties) so  there is nothing about the instances *to* change.

Comment: `myTest` is being sorted in ascending order. `backTest` is being sorted in descending order. I would expect that, after running, `int[] test` would contain `sortMe` in ascending order and that `int[] testBack` would contain `sortMe` in descending order. Instead what happens is that at first, `test` contains ascending order. But then when `testBack` runs, both contain the result from `testBack`. I don't understand why `backTest` is being treated as a reference to `myTest` instead of a unique object.

Comment: Because they're both returning the parameter, which they have modified in place.  They are both references to `sortMe` which has been modified in place.

Comment: neither myTest nor backTest are being sorted *at all* - they have no data.  The code passes external data to it as sortme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class is not returning a new array, it is modifying the input array and returning a reference to that. If your input is disposable, you could call your sort like this:

```
int[] test = myTest.BubbleSort(Sorting.GenerateTestArray(10, 100), false);
int[] testBack = backTest.BubbleSort(Sorting.GenerateTestArray(10, 100), true);
```

It would be clearer if you remove the return from your sort class. That way it's obvious it is modifying the first parameter, not making a new array.  For instance:

```
int[] test = Sorting.GenerateTestArray(10, 100);
myTest.BubbleSort(test, false);

int[] testBack = Sorting.GenerateTestArray(10, 100);
backTest.BubbleSort(testBack, true);
```

Comment: Best answer. In my original code, both instances reference `sortMe`. When they modify the array, they just pass the reference to the original array (which is now sorted) back, therefore each time I do an action on either one, it just updates `sortMe` which both instances reference. I will modify my sorts so that they return new, unique arrays.

Answer (score 0):

But they are both a reference to sortMe

You pass to sortMe to BubbleSort